# Perl: Removal element from an multiple array

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove value from array I have tried all the below 3 methods but dumper output before and after remains same.

@array:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'LINK-IF-A/1/1/1<->IF-B/1/1/1',
            'LINK-IF-C/1/1/1<->IF-D/1/1/1',
            'LINK-IF-E/1<->IF-F/2'
          ]
        ];
```

$value =  LINK-IF-C/1/1/1<->IF-D/1/1/1

```
Method1 :

my @remove = grep { $_ != "$value" } @array;

Method2 :

my @remove = grep { grep {!/$value/ } @$_ } @array;

Method3 :

my @remove = grep(!/"$value"/, @array);
```

DEBUG(Dumper\@remove));   --> Same output as input ...no removal

Thanks,

Comment: What should `@remove` consist of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for my $inner (@array) {
   @$inner = grep { $_ eq $value } @$inner;
}
```

Sorry, don't have time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

### [Codepad](http://codepad.org/5JD9hm8N)

One way is to loop through the array and grep each internal array:

```
my @remove = map { [ grep { !/$value/ } @$_ ] } @array;
```

If your outer array is really only an array of one element, you can avoid using `map` and pop the array off the stack:

```
my @remove =  [ grep { !/$value/ } @{$array[0]} ];
```

Comment: `@array` is an AoA, but `@remove` isn't. This can't be right.

Comment: @ikegami: You're right.  He should also include what `@remove` should look like, but I guess it should mimic @array as you suggest.  I may just delete this answer, since I'm beyond exhausted right now.  Or lazy man approach: rewrap array ref :)